# jQuery remove <tbody> with no content

Tags: jquery

```
<table id="test">
 <thead>Some Content</thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="9">Some TD content</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the above structure generates some empty `<tbody>`. How can I remove all `<tbody>` with no content ?

```
$("#tbodyid").empty();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just find any `tbody` that has no children, and remove it:

```
$("tbody").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length === 0;
}).remove();
```

More in the docs: [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter), [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children), [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove)

On any vaguely-modern browser, you can make that slightly more efficient, if it's important:

```
$("tbody").filter(function() {
    return !this.firstElementChild;
}).remove();
```

[`firstElementChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-parentnode-firstelementchild) is a DOM property that's the first **element** child of the element you use it on (ignoring non-element nodes like comment and text nodes). If it's `null`, then there are no children in the element.

Or as [Vohuman points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339585/jquery-remove-tbody-with-no-content/29339610#comment46866832_29339610), we can use the [`rows` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-tbody-rows):

```
$("tbody").filter(function() {
    return this.rows.length === 0;
}).remove();
```

Comment: One can also use the `rows` property. `this.rows.length === 0`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder would be using  `return this.rows.length === 0;`. Wonder who downvoted my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through `tbody` elements and verify if [`is(':empty')`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) (has no children). If has children use [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to delete it from page.

```
  $("#test tbody").each(function () {
     if($(this).is(':empty')) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test tbody").each(function () {
     if($(this).is(':empty')) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
 <thead>Some Content</thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="9">Some TD content</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find the `tbody` then use `each` and set a condition if the tbody has no elements inside probably empty.

```js
var tbody = $('table#test').find('tbody');

tbody.each(function(){
    if($(this).children().length === 0){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
 <thead>Some Content</thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="9">Some TD content</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this for remove empty tbody

> $("#test").find("tbody").each(function(){
>
> ```
> if($(this).children().length == 0)
> {
>     $(this).remove();
> }
> ```
>
> });

or you can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqjy3z85/)